# egrep AND condition on multiple patterns not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, grep

**egrep AND condition not working on the log file with below command:**

My command is:

```
egrep -E "20-Sep-20|^[ ]*|^[ ]*21-Sep-20.*6f0747e47829.*oMXskCaN0RWrdfT" file.log
```

Result:

> 21-Sep-20 14:30:40.223 DEBUG    6f0747e47829 QzAJ7ru4ayOWqRm
> oMXskCaN0RWrdfT prep -         ************** END ***************
> 21-Sep-20 14:30:40.223 INFO     6f0747e47829 QzAJ7ru4ayOWqRm
> oMXskCaN0RWrdfT prep - *************Data Prep Step
>
> ENDED***************** 21-Sep-20 14:30:40.273 INFO     6f0747e47829
> QzAJ7ru4ayOWqRm oMXskCaN0RWrdfT prep - dependency step has been
> removed with step_id = 9l2CDtSl2ZmTOUk  21-Sep-20 14:30:40.439 INFO
> 6f0747e47829 QzAJ7ru4ayOWqRm oMXskCaN0RWrdfT prep - Step run
> completed: success=True   22-Sep-20 14:30:40.500 INFO     6f0747e47829
> QzAJ7ru4ayOWqRm oMXskCaN0RWrdfT prep - dependency step has been
> removed with step_id = 9l2CDtSl2ZmTOUk 22-Sep-20 14:30:40.560 INFO
> 6f0747e47829 QzAJ7ru4ayOWqRm oMXskCaN0RWrdfT prep - Step run
> completed: success=True 22-Sep-20 14:30:40.600 ERROR    6f0747e47829
> QzAJ7ru4ayOWqRm oMXskCaN0RWrdfT- Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wiz_task/tasks/modeling/py_module.py",
> line 55, in run_py_module
> (success, reports) = instance.execute(project_id, process_id, module_name, step_name, run_params, **kwargs)   File
> "/code/test_module/domkar/py_code/python-attributor/attributor/module.py",
> line 62, in execute
> model2_out.main()   File "/code/test_module/domkar/py_code/python-attributor/attributor/model/model2.py",
> line 883, in main
> model_constr,FixedCoeffTable,planner,Output_data=self.model ()   File
> "/code/test_module/domkar/py_code/python-attributor/attributor/model/model2.py",
> line 503, in model
> model_constr_res = model_constr_worker.runSingleModel (cmodel_trfm_data_ref, model_constr, False)   File
> "/code/test_module/domkar/py_code/python-attributor/attributor/lib/algo/model_worker.py",
> line 1283, in runSingleModel
> model_result = self.runMixedModel (data, model, light_mode)   File "/code/test_module/domkar/py_code/python-attributor/attributor/lib/algo/model_worker.py",
> line 625, in runMixedModel
> return self.runLinearModel (data, model, light_mode)   File "/code/test_module/domkar/py_code/python-attributor/attributor/lib/algo/model_worker.py",
> line 597, in runLinearModel
> result.setRetention (DataUtility.retention (data, dep_var, date_var, fixed_vars, model.getHierarchyVars ()) )   File
> "/code/test_module/domkar/py_code/python-attributor/attributor/lib/data/data_utility.py",
> line 396, in retention
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa NameError: name 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' is not defined 23-Sep-20 14:30:40.439 INFO     6f0747e47829 QzAJ7ru4ayOWqRm
> oMXskCaN0RWrdfT prep - Step run completed: success=True

Expected Result:

When given an invalid string(pattern) AND condition fails and still returns the result but instead I need empty result. Because given patterns won't match from the file.

Comment: Puff, please take to time to reformat your post. Please post input and output and commands with leading 4 spaces - leading 4 spaces make it appear as within a code block, properly formatted.

Comment: To format your input and output as code by indenting it you can select the code you want to format and use the `{}` tool of the editor field. Alternatively you can put `~~~` on a line of its own before and after the code block. This way you don't need to indent it. I did this as an example with your command line.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you're trying to match? As it is, your pattern will match everything due to the second OR'ed sub-pattern (`^[ ]*` matches any number of non-space characters at the beginning of a line, including zero)

Comment: Please check and maybe fix the output shown in the question. The line breaks don't seem to be correct after an edit made by someone else. It might be easier to copy&paste and format it again.

Comment: @Pikrass I am trying get all lines between two dates with AND condition on two patterns. I am not sure what wrong i am doing. If i wont use date filter i end up missing multiple lines in between. So, i want all the lines between those date filter with AND condition on Matching patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, you're trying to match all lines between two patterns. This is not possible with grep, because grep works line-by-line. You can match one line, but by the next one grep can't know if it should match based solely on whether or not it matched before.

What you did is not an "AND condition", and I fail to understand what you mean by that. Perl regular expressions have a kind of "AND" clause (that's called a lookahead), but what it means is "at this point, the next characters should match both this pattern and this other pattern" (lookaheads are a bit more subtle than that but I'm simplifying). There's no way to use that for what you want.

For the sake of learning, let's analyze your pattern:

```
20-Sep-20|^[ ]*|^[ ]*21-Sep-20.*6f0747e47829.*oMXskCaN0RWrdfT
```

The `|` character means "**OR**". So you're matching any line that matches *either one* of these 3 patterns:

```
20-Sep-20
^[ ]*
^[ ]*21-Sep-20.*6f0747e47829.*oMXskCaN0RWrdfT
```

The second pattern means "any non-space character any number of times (including zero) at the beginning of a line". That matches everything. So grep will match every line of your input, and output it as-is.

---

What you actually want is "match this line, followed by any number of characters (including newlines), followed by this line". There's no "AND", that's a single pattern. But it needs to be applied on multiple lines at once, and grep can't do that.

There are however ways to do that using other programs. Here's an example with awk:

```
awk '/20-Sep-20/ { a=1 } ; { if (a == 1) print } ; /^[ ]*21-Sep-20.*6f0747e47829.*oMXskCaN0RWrdfT/ { exit }' file.log
```

What I'm doing here is, statement by statement:

- on lines matching "20-Sep-20", I set a variable "a" to 1.
- on all lines, print the line if "a" is 1
- on line matching "^[ ]*21-Sep-20.*6f0747e47829.*oMXskCaN0RWrdfT", exit (so it stops printing)

With the added requirement that the command should not return anything if the second pattern doesn't match, the most obvious solution I see is to first grep for it, and execute awk only if it matches.

```
end_pattern='^[ ]*21-Sep-20.*6f0747e47829.*oMXskCaN0RWrdfT'
grep -qE "$end_pattern" file.log && awk "/20-Sep-20/ { a=1 } ; { if (a == 1) print } ; /$end_pattern/ { exit }" file.log
```

That won't work if the second pattern is found before the first though.

Another completely different way I see to achieve this would be to grep the starting and ending lines with grep option "-n" to get the line numbers, then use head and tail (or sed) to get the range (if both patterns matched, and ending > starting).

And a third way would be to use a programming language with support for multi-line regular expressions.

Comment: I tried the above one with awk as suggested by you, but when i try to give a wrong pattern it should return me empty result.

Comment: on line matching "^[ ]*21-Sep-20.*6f0747e47829.*oMXskCaN0RWrdfT", exit (so it stops printing) -- If i pass a wrong pattern in place of 6f0747e47829 or oMXskCaN0RWrdfT, it still gives me the result, it should be an empty file as patterns did not match

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you a general answer to your question: how to create logical expressions in `grep`?

- OR can be handled with `grep -E "cond1|cond2"`
- AND can be handled with `grep "cond1" | grep "cond2"`

So if you want to grep, let's say on `cond1 AND (cond2 OR cond3)`, you need something like:

```
grep "cond1" | grep -E "cond2|cond3"
```

So, please, edit your question and clearly explain what are the conditions and their logical relationships.

Furthermore, as explained in the answer and the comments: `^[ ]*` means that your line might start with a space or not (which basically every line does), so don't use this anymore.

**Edit after comment**

As an example for your case: imagine you want to see the entries from 20 september or 21 september, who all must contain the string `"oMXskCaN0RWrdfT"`, you can do the following:

```
grep -E "20-Sep-20|21-Sep-20" file.log | grep "oMXskCaN0RWrdfT"
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. What i need is from the log file sample what i have posted i need the lines matching with pattern on AND condition with the lines in between those matching patterns. But i end up getting missed the in between lines which i need.

Comment: @90's_jaddu: I've edited my answer according to your comment, is this what you are looking for?